# Search string for sentence/word

Tags: php, string, search

I have a large text:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse tempor 
faucibus eros. Fusce ac lectus at risus pretium tempor. Curabitur vulputate 
eu nibh at consequat. find'someword' Curabitur id ipsum eget massa condimentum pulvinar in 
ac purus. Donec sollicitudin eros ornare ultricies tristique. find'someword2' Sed condimentum 
eros a ante tincidunt dignissim.
```

What would be the easiest way to search the string and return the word inbetween the apostrophe marks?

So far i've tried this:

```
$findme = array('find');
$hay = file_get_contents('text.txt');


foreach($findme as $needle){

    $search = strpos($hay, $needle);

    if($search !== false){
        //Return word inbetween apostrophe
    }
}
```

I know there's always the word find right before the apostrophe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not just use regex?

```
if(preg_match_all("/find'(.+?)'/", $hay, $matches)) {
    array_shift($matches);
    print_r($matches);
}
else {
    //no matches
}
```

**UPDATE:** If string "*find*" is not fixed, you can use a variable in its place, moreover, you can separate multiple words easily:

```
$prefix = "find|anotherword";
if(preg_match_all("/($prefix)'(.+?)'/", $hay, $matches)) {
    $matches = $matches[2];
    print_r($matches);
}
else {
    //no matches found
}
```

Comment: *A man once tried to fix a problem with a regular expression. Then he had two.*

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes I frankly don't understand the relevance of your comment.  He's looking for specific matches within the string - that's what regex is for.  If you know what you're doing, then you will solve a problem, not create more problems.  And in this case the issue is trivial.

Comment: If I understand the question correctly the `find` string is configurable or dependent on environment, otherwise why use an array. So the string could also be containing problematic words, thus needing escaping etc. If OP knew enough about regexps, he would've chosen this solution already, so apparently he doesn't, which might cause a lot of problems. Also, regexps are much more computationally expensive than simple `strpos` calls. I'm mainly trying to say regexps should be avoided unless they're defendably by far the best possible solution.

Comment: If I understand correctly, _find_ string is fixed for the search.  If it's configurable, then just use a variable instead.

Comment: This did the trick, thanks a lot! And @Niels Keutentjes, no I did not know about regexps. It's an array because i have multiple static "find" words but the apostrophe is always the same.

Comment: @Resitive If you have multiple static "find" works, you can use regex to match them all in one go - see my update